# Value dependent color in IcCube6

Tags: graphics, iccube, iccube-reporting

How can have the color of a bar to be value dependent in the iccube reporting version 6 ?

[image]

[image]

I see there is a dialog specifically for that, but not finding what to write inside.

Comment: We're already working on a new version of this widget, will be part of RC3. It will be a lot easier. Feel free to ask a prerelease version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of opportunities to set value based coloring without javascript expressions :

### Color Palette

Graph configuration's Color Mode option can be set to "Color Palette" based on cell Values:

[image]

For charts with large amount of values you might want to use Interpolation:

[image]

### Conditional Coloring (RC 3 feature)

Conditional coloring can be used for specific values and thresholds:

[image]